# Is it possible to divide two numerics in swift?

Tags: swift, generics, numeric

```
func divtwoval<T: Numeric>(_a: T,_b: T){
        let c = _a / _b
        print(c)
    }
```

I tried to divide two numeric generics but it doesent work.
I get this error message: error: binary operator '/' cannot be applied to two 'T' operands.

How do I divide this generics?

Comment: You can use FloatingPoint

Comment: In the general case, no. Division (e.g. the `/`, `/=` operators) is defined on the `BinaryInteger` and `FloatingPoint` protocols. They have slightly differing semantics between the two of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/numeric) of `Numeric`, it clearly shows its values only need to support multiplication.

The division operator (`/`) is defined on the `BinaryInteger` and `FloatingPoint` protocols separately, since they have different semantics, so you cannot divide any numeric types by each other.